# After Exporting blog from wordpress to blogger,image links not updated

Tags: html, wordpress, templates, blogger

I had exported a blog from  wordpress to blogger.

But the images in the post  show the links from old wordpress site.

What could be the possible solution?

Comment: try asking this on wordpress.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to explain the steps you followed. Please go through the following link and see if you missed anything or you did something wrong.

http://google.about.com/od/googleblogger/a/How-To-Move-Your-Blog-From-Wordpress-To-Blogger.htm